# Python3 - Import another Python file in Linux from user directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python file running on /home/app that needs to import a python script from:

> /home/app2/

At the top of my file I have:

```
import app2
sys.path.insert(1, '/home/app2/')
```

However when running the script I get:

> No module named app2

Is there something I am doing wrong? The name of the class I want to import is called {app2} in this case

I am using Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of those lines? Inserting app2 in your path and then importing?

Comment: @CollinHeist Funny enough the Visual Studio Code with Python extension is forcing the import statements on top anytime I save the file. I have tried that but assumed since the extension is doing it it must be valid

Comment: @CollinHeist Just tried it, no difference

Comment: What about `sys.path.insert(1, '../app2/')` before the first `import app2` statement - assuming your executing the script in `/home/app/` as you said.

Comment: @CollinHeist It worked your last answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I just created the files and folders `/home/app/test.py` and `/home/app2/test2.py`.

Within `/home/app/test.py` I have the following:

```py
def test():
    print('working!')
```

And within `/home/app2/test2.py` I have:

```
from sys import path
path.insert(1, '../app/')
import test

test.test()
```

Which then prints `working!`. So the trick is:

```py
from sys import path
path.insert(1, '../app/') # Can use absolute paths here if desired
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

When you add /home/app2 to your path, the interpreter is looking there for the module you're trying to import. In the case of your example, it's looking in /home/app2 for...app2. Try this instead:

```
sys.path.insert(1,'/home')
import app2
```